# Copy from a cd specific file types to a new folder on a usb stick Windows

Tags: windows, usb, batch, script, file-transfer

Trying to make a batch file that will copy a specific file type from a CD and put it in a new folder with a prompt for choice of destination folder name. I've had a hard time explaining how to find files on a number of older users how to transfer files to a usb stick, so I'm hoping for a one double click answer.

I've tried a few variations of xcopy, but it didn't have any output as far as I can tell.

D drive being the CD drive, and E being the usb drive. The files I'm searching for in the CD are buried through several folders deep.

Not attached to a batch file if there is a better way to do this. 
Thanks.

```
@echo off
set /p x= 
xcopy "D:\" "E:\%x%\" .*pes /s
```

Tried running it from the E drive to simplify,

```
xcopy E:\ *.pes /s
```

It does copy, but it copies the entire directory... and makes all files into .pes instead of only copying the .pes now.

Comment: take the space out. xcopy E:\*.pes D: /s

Comment: I feel incredibly stupid now. Thank you LarryC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work like this:

```
@echo off
set /p x= 
xcopy "D:\*.pes" "E:\%x%\" /s
```

But the folder structure of the source will also be created at the destination.

To copy all files in only one folder, this might get used:

```
@echo off
set /p x= 
for /r "D:\" %%i in (*.pes) do xcopy "%%~fi" "E:\%x%\"
```

**Edit to clarify/research:**

FOR /R = recursive FOR loop (https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)

%%i = variable for every file

(*.pes) = every file in the folder / subfolders that ends with .pes

This doesn't seem to be necessary: "%%~fi"

%%~fi = "expands %%i to a fully qualified path name" (See FOR /? in CMD)

It also seems to work like this:

```
for /r "D:\" %%i in (*.pes) do xcopy "%%i" "E:\%x%\"
```

Comment: The first part I understand, but how does the second part work? A for loop that checks each file and then xcopys those with .pes endings?

Comment: @SewMachineSewBusy I have added some explanation